# Python: File not formatting like it should

Tags: python

The could below doesnt write to the text file as it should:

```
import re

download_results = open('download_result.txt', 'w')
s = 'AAAAAAABBBBCDEEEEEFFFFFFFFFFFFFGGGGGGGGGGGG##GGGGGGHHHHHHHHHHHHHHIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIJJJJJJJJJJJJJJKKKKKKKKKKKKLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLMMMMMMM&&MMMMMMMMNNNNNNNNNNNNOOOOOOOOOOOO'
s = re.sub(r'[^\w]','',s)
s = ''.join(s)
for i in range(0, len(s), 60):
    download_results.write('%s' % (s[i:i+60]))
download_results.write('\n\n')
download_results.close()
```

The output in the text file is:

```
AAAAAAABBBBCDEEEEEFFFFFFFFFFFFFGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGHHHHHHHHHHHHHHIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIJJJJJJJJJJJJJJKKKKKKKKKKKKLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMNNNNNNNNNNNNOOOOOOOOOOOO
```

But i would like the output to be:

```
AAAAAAABBBBCDEEEEEFFFFFFFFFFFFFGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGHHHHHHHHHHH
HHHIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIJJJJJJJJJJJJJJKKKKKKKKKKKKLLLLLLLLLLLLLL
LLMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMNNNNNNNNNNNNOOOOOOOOOOOO
```

Where the script writes "S" in lines containing 60 characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
download_results.write('%s' % (s[i:i+60]))
```

to this:

```
download_results.write('%s\n' % (s[i:i+60]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Then append a newline in your `write` call within the loop - `write()` doesn't automatically add a newline, unlike `print`.

```
for i in range(0, len(s), 60):
    download_results.write('%s\n' % (s[i:i+60]))
download_results.write('\n')
download_results.close()
```

Comment: I think you wanted that `.write('\n')` to be in the for loop... it's not.

Comment: No, I didn't. The newline written in the loop is the one in `'%s\n'` - the extra one written is to mirror the `write('\n\n')` in the OP's code.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't writing any newline characters to the file.

Answer (score 0):

Add a newline to the `.write` invocation. `write` doesn't add a newline itself (`print` does, which might have been what confused you)